# error 500 on php form submission

Tags: php, forms, internal-server-error

I'm trying to add a simple contact form with a recaptcha to my website, and have not been very successful. I keep receiving an error 500 whenever I try to test my form. The form points to separate php file located on my server.

I'm really new to php, and I'm struggling to find out what's wrong. Here's the html for the form:

```
<form method="post" action="form.php" id="contact-form" class="col s12">   
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col m6 s12">
            <input id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
            <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col m6 s12">
            <input id="last_name" type="text" class="validate">
            <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="email" type="email" class="validate"required>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <textarea id="msg" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
            <label for="msg">Message</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m6">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxx-Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" data-type="image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col s12 m6">
            <button class="btn btn-large waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Send Message</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here's `form.php`:

```
<?php
$secret='xxx-Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$sitekey='xxx-Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$first_name=$last_name=$email=$msg="";

$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
}
$msg = test_input($_POST["msg"]);

if (isset($_POST['first_name'])) {
    $first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
          $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['last_name'])) {
    $last_name=$_POST['last_name'];
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
          $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
}
$response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=".$captcha);
if ($response.success==false) {
    echo '<p>Captcha failed.<p>'
    exit;
}

$toEmail='contact@example.org';

$message = '<p><b>First Name: </b>'.$first_name.'</p>'.
'<p><b>Last Name: </b>'.$last_name.'</p>'.
'<p><b>Email: </b>'.$email.'</p>'.
'<p><b>Message: </b><br/>'.$msg.'</p>';
$headers = 'From: first last <contact@example.org> '."rn".
'Reply-To: '.$first_name.$last_name.' <'.$email.'> '. "rn".
'Content-type: text/html'. "rn".
'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();

$message2 = '<p><b>Here is a copy of your message: </b><br/><br/>'.$first_name.' '.$last_name.'wrote: <br/><br/></p>'.'<p>'.$msg'</p>' 
$headers2 = 'From:'.$toEmail."rn".'Reply-To: '.$toEmail."rn".
'Content-type: text/html'. "rn".
'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();

mail($toEmail,'New Inquery from Website',$message,$headers);
mail($email,'Copy of your form submission',$message2,$headers2);


function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
?>
```

Is there something wrong with my php/html? Or is it something else? My webserver uses php5-fpm and nginx on Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Line

```
echo '<p>Captcha failed.<p>'
```

closing `;` missed

Line

```
$message2 = '<p><b>Here is a copy of your message: </b><br/><br/>'.$first_name.' '.$last_name.'wrote: <br/><br/></p>'.'<p>'.$msg'</p>'
```

should be

```
$message2 = '<p><b>Here is a copy of your message: </b><br/><br/>'.$first_name.' '.$last_name.'wrote: <br/><br/></p><p>'.$msg.'</p>';
```

Also, put

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

in the beginning of your PHP file (afrer `<?php` ) to view & debug errors.

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML submit button to

```
<button class="btn btn-large waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action" value="Send Message">Send Message</button>
```

And modify your php script. Put your code within

> if statement

e.g

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['action']))
{
    $secret='xxx-Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $sitekey='xxx-Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $first_name=$last_name=$email=$msg="";

    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
          $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
    }
    $msg = test_input($_POST["msg"]);

    if (isset($_POST['first_name'])) {
        $first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
              $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
        }
    }
    if (isset($_POST['last_name'])) {
        $last_name=$_POST['last_name'];
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
              $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
        }
    }
    $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=".$captcha);
    if ($response.success==false) {
        echo '<p>Captcha failed.<p>';
        exit;
    }

    $toEmail='contact@example.org';

    $message = '<p><b>First Name: </b>'.$first_name.'</p>'.
    '<p><b>Last Name: </b>'.$last_name.'</p>'.
    '<p><b>Email: </b>'.$email.'</p>'.
    '<p><b>Message: </b><br/>'.$msg.'</p>';
    $headers = 'From: first last <contact@example.org> '."rn".
    'Reply-To: '.$first_name.$last_name.' <'.$email.'> '. "rn".
    'Content-type: text/html'. "rn".
    'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();

    $message2 = '<p><b>Here is a copy of your message: </b><br/><br/>'.$first_name.' '.$last_name.'wrote: <br/><br/></p>'.'<p>'.$msg'</p>' 
    $headers2 = 'From:'.$toEmail."rn".'Reply-To: '.$toEmail."rn".
    'Content-type: text/html'. "rn".
    'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();

    mail($toEmail,'New Inquery from Website',$message,$headers);
    mail($email,'Copy of your form submission',$message2,$headers2);
    }

    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }
?>
```